# History of unlock patterns

Tags: lock-screens, pattern-lock

I have a Samsung Galaxy J3 (2016) on Android 5.1 Lollipop unlocked (with ADB and TWRP). I want to see an unlock pattern that I used a few months ago.

Is there a way to see the previous unlock patterns that I've been using before?

---

A few months ago, I broke my phone with a pattern lock. Until that, I had been using another phone and I used the same password. But months later, I changed the pattern and I forgot the previous one, which I used on my broken phone.

A few days ago, I have my phone, but when I try to put my pattern, it was incorrect. Now I'm trying different methods, like bugs or tricks, doing backup, and more, but none of them works.

Also, do you know a way to unlock the phone? Normally, I use the fingerprint, but anyways, you restart your device and it asks you for the password. It's a Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 and I think the USB debugging is on.

Comment: Hello. What problem are you trying to solve with this? Also, it is unlikely system would store this thing even in memory, let alone the persistent storage.

Comment: A few months ago, i brake my phone, with a pattern lock, until that, i been use another phone, and I use the same password, but months later I change my pattern and i forgoted the previous, which i use to my broked phone,a few days ago,i have my phone, but when i try to put mi pattern, it was incorrect , now im trying different methods,like bugs or tricks,do backup and more, but any of them works. Also, you know a way to unlock the phone? Normally i use the fingerprint but anyways you restart your device its lend you the password.. Its a Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 and I think the usb debugging is on.

Comment: Even I have the same problem. I have forgot my pattern on Motorola One Power(having stock android) when I switched to my new Samsung phone. Now I want to access some files on my old phone but I cannot unlock it. I have already entered 32 wrong patterns.